# Registro dentro de registro en C - Error unknow type name

Tags: c

Tengo un error en la linea de " t_gastos gastos[MAX_GASTOS];" y no se de que es. Lo que pretendo hacer en el programa es llamar la estructura de gastos, dentro la estructura de departamentos, y le pongo como nombre GASTOS, pero no se que es lo que me ocasiona el error.

```
#define MAX_GASTOS 10
 typedef struct departamentos{
    int num_depto;
    char nombre[50];
    int num_piso;
    char letra_depto[1];
    t_gastos gastos[MAX_GASTOS]; }t_departamentos; typedef struct gastos{
    int importe;
    char conceptos[50]; }t_gastos;
```

Acá realizo la carga de los datos:

```
int cargar(t_departamentos depto[], int cant){   int i;   int cont=1;  do {
    for (i=0;i<cont;i++) {
        printf("\n----------------------Carga de datos----------------------\n");
        printf("Ingrese el Numero de departamento\n");
        scanf("%d",&depto[i].num_depto);
        getchar ();
        printf("Ingrese nombre y apellido del propietario\n");
        gets(depto[i].nombre);
        printf("Ingrese el piso del departamento\n");
        scanf("%d",&depto[i].num_piso);
        getchar();
        printf("Ingrese la letra del departamento\n");
        gets(depto[i].letra_depto);
        printf("Ingrese el concepto\n");
        gets(depto[i].gastos.concepto);
        printf("Ingrese el impote\n");
        scanf("%d",&depto[i].gastos.importe);
        cant++;
    }
    printf("Desea continuar? 1 si 0 no\n");
    scanf("%d",&cont);   }while(cont!=0); }
```

Y acá los muestro:

```
void mostrarVec(t_departamentos depto[], int cant){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<cant;i++){
      printf("APELLIDO\t\tPISO\t\tDEPTO\n%s\t\t\t%d-%s\t\t%d\n",depto[i].nombre,depto[i].num_piso,depto[i].letra_depto,depto[i].num_depto);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declara primero el tipo de los gastos, no he tenido problema para compilar esto:

```
#define MAX_GASTOS 10
typedef struct gastos {
    int importe;
    char conceptos[50]; 
} t_gastos;

typedef struct departamentos{
    int num_depto;
    char nombre[50];
    int num_piso;
    char letra_depto[1];
    t_gastos gastos[MAX_GASTOS]; 
} t_departamentos;
```

incluso separando el `typedef`, es necesario declarar primero la estructura del registro `gastos`. Esto también compila sin problemas:

```
typedef struct departamentos t_departamentos;
typedef struct gastos t_gastos;

struct gastos {
    int importe;
    char conceptos[50]; 
};

struct departamentos{
    int num_depto;
    char nombre[50];
    int num_piso;
    char letra_depto[1];
    t_gastos gastos[MAX_GASTOS]; 
};
```

Pero esto no compila:

```
typedef struct departamentos t_departamentos;
typedef struct gastos t_gastos;

struct departamentos{
    int num_depto;
    char nombre[50];
    int num_piso;
    char letra_depto[1];
    t_gastos gastos[MAX_GASTOS]; 
}; 

struct gastos {
    int importe;
    char conceptos[50]; 
};
```

En mi compilador, obtengo el error:

> ```
> main.c:21:14: error: array type has incomplete element type ‘t_gastos {aka struct gastos}’
>     t_gastos gastos[MAX_GASTOS]; 
>           ^
> ```

Comment: Ya descubrí porque es el error. Es extraño, pero la estructura que llamo (gastos) tiene que estar antes que la estructura de departamentos, lo cambié de lugar y me funcionó

Comment: Es exactamente lo que te digo en mi respuesta, que gastos debe definirse antes. :)